# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSSRProps')

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering, nuxt3, getserversideprops

on reloading the page, got 500error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSSRProps')

at _sfc_ssrRender (C:\Mansi\smicolon-next\components\ValueProject\MultipleSlect.js:39:28)
at renderComponentSubTree (C:\Mansi\smicolon-next\node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:683:9)
at renderComponentVNode (C:\Mansi\smicolon-next\node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:631:12)
at Module.ssrRenderComponent (C:\Mansi\smicolon-next\node_modules@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:86:10)

Here are the components
multipleSelect.vue

```
<script lang="ts" setup>

const { handleChangeCheckbox, formError, formData } = defineProps(['handleChangeCheckbox', 'formError', 'formData']);

</script>
```

Parent component

```
<template>
<div class="inner-content">
   <MultipleSlect :handleChangeCheckbox="handleChangeCheckbox" :formError="formError"                 :formData="formData" />
</div>
</template>
```

how do I resolve this issue

Comment: I experienced a similar issue with scroll reveal. This would happen when you call a directive (registered as a plugin in `/plugins` ) in your template when you didn't create a server side version (`/plugins/myPlugin.server.ts`). I did that and it still didn't work for me, so my made sure that template is rendered only on client side by wrapping the particular element on the template with the `<client-only></client-only>` tag